# Detect if ThreadPool task is still in progress

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, threadpool

If I add a slower task to `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, how can I detect if the task is still in progress?

On the click of a button I want to display a pre-loader graphic while the task is in progress, and then hide it when it is complete and display a dialog.

```
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    protected Button myButton;
    private Dialog myDialog;
    private ManualResetEvent slowEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        **setup myButton & myDialog**
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => slowTask());
    }

    private void slowTask()
    {
        **do some slow stuff**
        slowEvent.Set();
    }

    protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        **display pre-loader graphic if task is still running**
        popupMenuDialog.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: why not a tasks api https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/ ? async method 1. show popup 2. await for background task 3. dismiss popup

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a method which you have to call instead of operating with `ThreadPool` directly. Instead of

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => slowTask());
```

You will do

```
Start(slowTask);
// Start(() => slowTask());
```

Where

```
public void Start(Action action)
{
    ... // 1

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    {
        ... // 2

        action();

        ... // 3

    });

    ... // 4
}
```

Notice placeholders `1` (before action is queued), `2` (action is about to execute), `3` (action finished) and `4` (action queued). You can use them either directly call something or simply rise events (which something else can use to listen to).